# Lightbox Plus captions spill over

Tags: css, wordpress, lightbox

I am using Lightbox Plus for Wordpress.  My captions are spilling over and overlapping the picture when the image is in lightbox mode. The captions are covering the image and the close link, as well as being off-center. Here is my URL: http://dev.andreamarymarshall.com/archives/2012-2/

How do I make the space allowed for the captions bigger, so that in fits at least two lines of text without overlapping anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on your other image pages you are using a different lightbox plugin. Possibly Thickbox/Colorbox as they seem to use different CSS, plus prev/next are missing.

Best best would to check if you have any other plugins or check the advanced settings of your working image pages to see if there is a custom class being used in there somewhere.

Hope this helps ;)